# NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401

Tags: android, laravel, response

> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.446  4541-4582  Volley   E  [45] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.0.107/api/user/login
>
> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.468  1397-1397  Layer                   surfaceflinger                       D  reparent to null sequence=91059, seq[49], name=Surface(name=f621fd4 com.dskysolution.booklib/com.dskysolution.booklib.LoginActivity)/@0x7911dbe - animation-leash of window_animation#91059
>
> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.468  1397-1397  OplusLayer              surfaceflinger                       D  ~Layer() sequence=91059, name=Surface(name=f621fd4 com.dskysolution.booklib/com.dskysolution.booklib.LoginActivity)/@0x7911dbe - animation-leash of window_animation#91059
>
> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.688  4541-4582  Volley     E  [45] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.0.107/api/user/login
>
> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.691  2112-10814 CoreBackPreview         system_server                        D  Window{f621fd4 u0 com.dskysolution.booklib/com.dskysolution.booklib.LoginActivity}: Setting back callback null
>
> 2023-07-19 12:17:20.697  4541-4568  BufferQueueProducer  D  VRI[LoginActivity]#1(BLAST Consumer)1 disconnect: api 1

**login Method**

```
public function userLogin(Request $request)
    {

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return $this->error($validator->errors()->all(),401);
            }

            if (auth()->guard('user')->attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {

                config(['auth.guards.api.provider' => 'user']);

                $user = User::select('users.*')->find(auth()->guard('user')->user()->id);
                $success =  $user;
                $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp', ['user'])->accessToken;

                return $this->success($success);
            } else {
                return $this->error("Your credential not match.",401);
            }
    }
```